# Трансляция текст из сайта в программу

Tags: c#, .net, парсер

У меня есть сайт на котором есть text файл к примеру [http://сайт.com/text.txt](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.com/text.txt)
и я хочу использовать текст из text файла в элементе lable чтобы при надобности можно было изменить этот текст на сайте и текст поменялся и в самой программе,
я искал информацию об этом но так и не нашел можете перевести пример как это должно выглядеть в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Самый тривиальный вариант - это скачать файл, прочитать его, удалить файл. Тут нет ничего сложного, так что код писать я не буду.

Но, есть вариант и поинтереснее:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000];
        int len;
        while ((len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            // Работаете с данными
            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```